# When i share a dynamic table from excel to another person they have trouble of compatibility

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dynamic-tables

I created an Excel Workbook, there are 2 dynamic tables in this workbook, the dynamic tables get feed with information from a data that is in power pivot, the same data from power pivot gets feed from data of Access, the problems is that when i share this Workbook with other people from work they have problems using the filter of the dynamic table because it just keeps loading and never ends, these people dont have access to the database from Access, I want to know how to solve this problem so that I canshare the Workbook to these people without having to share the database from Access.

Answer (score 0):

Those opening the file eother needs to have access to the external data, or you need to create a copy of the file. You can remove the external data connection before sharing the copy.

Comment: How can i do this? And if I do this, would I be able to set the connection back again without having to transfer the data again? Please let me know, because if not i would just have to create a copy an remove the connection so that i can send it, but please let me know how can I remove the connection.

Comment: Indeed, only remove the connection on a copy. I will update the answer.

Comment: There are multiple ways, please search for "excel remove external data connection"

Comment: Ok so i tried removing the data source from the pivot tables, and the only problems is that after i remove this links it doesnt let me use the filter of the pivot table, it only keeps values and format, I think that it is because my pivot table is getting its data from the Access database, however I've created this pivot table using the Data model from the Workbook, if you can help please let me know, also if you need the database and excel just let me know

Comment: The data connection you need to remove is the one to the Access database. The data needs to be static in the Excel file. If the data is too much for that, then you need the link to the Access database. If so, then the best option is to let those who need the data also be able to read the data source.
All in all, the details and the options are too many for me to be able to do your work for you.